# Connection falied: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm on Windows 10 and I'm using WAMP. I am trying to create a login form with prepared PDO statements. Below is the code to my connect.php script that is issuing the error: "Connection failed: could not find driver".

```
<?php

$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = 'login';

try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysqli:host=$server;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected Successfully";
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection falied: " . $e->getMessage();
}
 ?>
```

This is a list from my php.ini file that shows and DLLs associated with pdo

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

WAMP says "no dll file" for:
    -php_mysqli
    -php_pdo

I have the "php_pdo" dll file in wamp/bin/php5.6.25/ and in wamp/bin/php5.6.25/ext/ just in case.
I can't find a download for php_mysqli but I don't think I need that for PDO, though it would be nice to have if anyone has a download link.

So my question is, did I just install the dll file into the wrong directory, or what? I'm not sure what to do, But I just installed WAMP and I can't use PDO. Should I use another client(I'm not sure what they are called).

Comment: If you dont have FireBird installed comment `;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll` as that will produce an error unless it can find `fbclient.dll` as well

Comment: Also comment out `;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll` if you dont have the Oracle client installed _same reason_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo, try `mysql` instead of `msqli`:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
```

Also from comments:

1. Try to put this in the php.ini : extension_dir = "c:\php5\ext" and point to the extension
2. move php_pdo.dll before the other PDO extensions, and restart WAMP

Comment: Can you see any entries with PDO when you execute `php -m` in command line?

Comment: Try to put this in the php.ini : `extension_dir = "c:\php5\ext"` and point to the extension

Comment: And move php_pdo.dll before the other PDO extensions, and restart WAMP

Comment: I noticed the edit here where I did post my answer before that.

Comment: I saw your answer and corrected, I only noticed the typo at first. Thanks

Comment: Kind of overstepping, wouldn't you agree? Either way, the OP has their answer. I'll just go now.

Comment: "wamp is great and I never had any problems with it" is not really any help no?

Comment: *"wamp is great"* - Huh? You're putting words into my mouth here. Where did you get that from? Plus, the OP didn't follow specific instructions upon reading what should have been the official manuals. Please don't patronize me, I simply said in my answer that I never had a problem with installing Wamp (or xampp) for that matter. If they can't follow manuals by the book and the syntax, then the question's off-topic as a typo. And if you're simply for points here, take them they're all yours. People aren't stupid you know. They'll see the edit without marking it as an edit.

Comment: The point of any answer and comment is to try to address the question in cause and help the OP out of the situation, not to state the obvious. Please stick to that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127454/discussion-between-elzo-valugi-and-fred-ii).

Comment: I don't want to chat about it; the OP can choose your answer if they want to, that's up to them. I just need to set the record straight here. You could have at the very least made a note/mention about what I wrote, but you chose to just "edit" and not say a word. The matter is close for me, far as I'm concerned. I just don't care much for what you said I said, which was a lie "wamp is great", you said that, I didn't. I also added more information about their probable choice of installation. Let's just leave it at that.

Comment: I don't find that funny. Unless there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: Adding `extension_dir = "c:\php5\ext"` would break PHP as WAMPSever puts its PHP inside the `\wamp\php\php{version}` folder **DONT DO THAT**

Comment: And its extensions inside `\wamp\php\php{version}\ext`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I decided to change my answer to be a community wiki, since I feel there should not be any rep that should come of this. Plus, the question being a typo on more than one count.

---

Original answer:

The syntax is:

- `mysql:host`

and not `mysqli`. I hope this isn't another "typo" as per your original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40444027/1 of `new PDO("msqli:host`

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

As per the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Note: Wamp should be ready to use "out of the box" and not require any drivers to be added.

I use Wamp also and xampp and never had a problem.

Plus, Wamp installation comes in different flavours (32 and 64 bit), so make sure you chose the right one.

- http://www.wampserver.com/en/

You can also try installing xampp

- https://www.apachefriends.org/

Use error reporting also, which would have been of help here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: This answer was posted before the unmarked edit of the other answer, where the other person answering should have spotted the `mysqli` right off the bat, even before the original post of the typo. I know my PDO syntax. It's pretty obvious here that they saw my answer before they made the edit. I don't care for the points on this, it's the principle of the matter. Plus, I don't care for having words put into my mouth. I know what I said and what I did "not" say, so let's just keep the record straight.